# ¿Como hago esta petición con cURL en Php?

Tags: php, curl

Estoy implementando un servicio de pagos en mi web, y uno de los ultimos es hacer una peticion `http` con `curl`, pero no entiendo del todo como hacerlo.

La documentación dice que la petición debe tener la siguiente forma:

```
https://sandbox.affirm.com/api/v2/charges
     -X POST
     -u "<public_api_key>:<private_api_key>"
     -H "Content-Type: application/json"
     -d '{"checkout_token": "<checkout_token>","order_id": "JKLM4321"}'
```

La forma en que tengo que llevar a cabo esto con curl, seria la siguiente:

```
// Iniciar curl
$curl = curl_init();
$headers[]  = 'Content-Type: application/json';
// Agregar las opciones y datos
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://sandbox.affirm.com/api/v2/charges',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        checkout_token => 'value',
        order_id => 'value2'
    ]
]);
// Enviar la petición y obtener la respuesta
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Cerrar la peticion
curl_close($curl);
```

Pero, como se observa, no tengo idea de como incluir las llaves publicas y privadas (que ya tengo, eso NO es el problema) en la petición con `curl`, y tampoco se que significa ese "-u" que describen en la documentación. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La `u` por la que preguntas, corresponde a la opción [`CURLOPT_USERPWD`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php) de `cURL`, como podrás verificar en el ejemplo de código más abajo.

[En la página de la API](https://docs.affirm.com/Integrate_Affirm/Direct_API/Example_Code) tienes un ejemplo de código PHP usando `cURL`:

```
<?
php $checkout_token = $_REQUEST['checkout_token'];

//These are sandbox credentials
// $public_key = "ARQBLCL7NAMBTZ7F";                  //descomentar y poner tus credenciales
// $private_key = "RkHBmVSP5ayC2rCUujwhArpGWPxpuTtv"; //descomentar y poner tus credenciales
//This is the sandbox API URL
$url = "https://sandbox.affirm.com/api/v2/charges/";

$data = array("checkout_token" => $checkout_token);
$json = json_encode($data);
$header = array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($json));

$keypair = $public_key . ":" . $private_key;

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);                                                                     
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $keypair);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl);

http_response_code($status);
echo $response;
?>
```

Sólo tienes que descomentar y cambiar esto por tus credenciales reales y debería funcionar:

```
// $public_key = "ARQBLCL7NAMBTZ7F"; 
// $private_key = "RkHBmVSP5ayC2rCUujwhArpGWPxpuTtv";
```